# Unable to create index using cypher in gremlin

Tags: cypher, gremlin

I am unable to create index on Node properties in gremlin using the following command:

```
create index on :account(node_id)
```

But running this gives me the following error:

```
gremlin> :> create index on :account(node_id)
```

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.console.RemoteException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: CreateIndex(LabelName(account),List(PropertyKeyName(node_id))) (of class org.opencypher.v9_0.ast.CreateIndex)
        at org.opencypher.gremlin.console.jsr223.CypherRemoteAcceptor.submit(CypherRemoteAcceptor.java:108)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.commands.SubmitCommand.execute(SubmitCommand.groovy:41)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.execute(Shell.groovy:104)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.super$2$execute(Groovysh.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.executeCommand(Groovysh.groovy:273)
```

Am I using a wrong query here?

Comment: i assume you're using the cypher-for-gremlin plugin? do you have a more complete stacktrace (if its not appearing in the console, it might be on the server log output)?

Comment: @stephenmallette I've updated the logs. Please have a look. And yes I'm using 
 the cypher-for-gremlin plugin